# Optimistic locking in a single update statement

Tags: database, transactions

If I have two threads updating a database in separate transactions with statements that look like

Thread 1

```
UPDATE people set id='12346' WHERE name='Jeff'
```

Thread 2

```
UPDATE people SET name = 'Jeff' WHERE id='12345'
```

Obviously there is a race here. If Thread 1 changes the id before Thread 2, 12345 will be an invalid ID (assuming no one else is using it).

What I'm wondering is, when using optimistic locking, is this a situation in which an optimistic lock error may be thrown (e.g. a stale record error)? Does the UPDATE/WHERE constitute a read and write or is each UPDATE executed an atomic statement (or does it vary by database)?

Comment: updates are atomic statements on SQL Server, and I believe most other major RDBMS

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133393/is-update-with-nested-select-atomic-operation

Comment: That looks to be a slightly more specific question.  This one appears to pertain only to the handling of concurrent updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very poor form for a DBMS to not implement updates as atomic statements, but it's worth verifying this for you particular environment to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, that'w what I was assuming but wanted to confirm.